# Testing a List inside of an Table if it is != 0

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to mathematica so I hope this is not a too stupid question, but I couldn't find a solution in the mathematica documentation.

I've got a normal table, initialized with "0" as entries. In the first element, I want to put a List of few numbers. I tried to build a minimalistic example as follows:

```
visitedNodes = Table[0,{i,1,5}]
visitedNodes[[1]] = List[1,2,3]
```

so visitedNodes = {{1,2,3},0,0,0,0}. Now I test:

```
For[i=1, i <= Length[visitedNodes], i++,
    If[visitedNodes[[i]] != 0, 
        a = 5;   (* like: "do something" *)
        Print["I'm in!"];
    ];
];
```

Since it's a "List Object", for me it's != 0, but guess I have to test it on somewhat else... but on what? :)
Thank you a lot, this site also helped me already a lot =).

Edit: The question is, that the If statement for i=1 should be like "Yes, a List[1,2,3] is not equal 0, since it's the first element of visitedNodes", but it does not. So why is it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `visitedNodes[[i]] =!= 0`

and check [`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unequal.html) vs [`UnsameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnsameQ.html).

Comment: =!= works, thanks a lot :)
Edit: Oh, I see the difference between Unequal vs. UnsameQ. Didn't knew about UnsameQ :). Thanks!